# asp.net MVC upload file with subfolder path using DropZone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, upload, dropzone.js

Assalamualaikum,
in ASP.NET MVC, I can upload file by DropZone. Here, if I drag and drop any folder contains sub folders and file, it upload only all files from all sub folder, in a server upload folder. But I want to upload those file with its sub folder name. This sub folder name can be store in DB or create new folder.

For example uploading file / folder in google drive.

Here is my uploading code (Only the functional code here) :

```
public void Upload()
{
    bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
    string fName = "";

    try
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {

            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            fName = file.FileName;


            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid GuidFileName = Guid.NewGuid();
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/_UploadedFile"));
                    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString());
                    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                    if (!isExists) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                    var uploadpath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", pathString, GuidFileName.ToString(), ext.ToString());
                    file.SaveAs(uploadpath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSavedSuccessfully = false;
    }
    if (isSavedSuccessfully)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Now, please help me to get sub folder's name from file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

to upload files with their subfolder names using the Dropzone library in ASP.NET MVC. you need to modify the server-side code that handles the file upload to include the subfolder name in the file path.

Example

```
public void Upload()
{
    bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
    string fName = "";

    try
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            fName = file.FileName;

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Guid GuidFileName = Guid.NewGuid();

                    // Get the subfolder name from a separate input field or database
                    string subfolderName = "my_subfolder";

                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/_UploadedFile"), subfolderName);
                    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString());
                    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                    if (!isExists) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                    var uploadpath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", pathString, GuidFileName.ToString(), ext.ToString());
                    file.SaveAs(uploadpath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle any exceptions that occur during file upload
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSavedSuccessfully = false;
        // Handle any exceptions that occur during the file upload process
    }

    if (isSavedSuccessfully)
    {
        // Handle the success case
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the failure case
    }
}
```

In this modified code, the subfolder name is obtained from a separate input field or database (in this case, the subfolder name is hardcoded to "my_subfolder" for illustration) and is appended to the upload path using the Path.Combine method. This will create a new subfolder in the _UploadedFile directory with the specified subfolder name, and save the uploaded file in that subfolder with a unique file name generated using a Guid.

Comment: Thanks for your code and feedback. I can upload file in a sub folder by hardcode the subfolder name. But I need to retrieve sub folder name from user upload's file/folder name. As like Google Drive, I want to make a upload system.

Thanks